# SQL left join on maximum date

Tags: postgresql, optimization, sql-tuning

I have two tables: `contracts` and `contract_descriptions`.

On `contract_descriptions` there is a column named `contract_id` which is equal on `contracts` table records.

I am trying to join the latest record on `contract_descriptions`:

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN contract_descriptions d ON d.contract_id = c.contract_id
AND d.date_description =
  (SELECT MAX(date_description)
   FROM contract_descriptions t
   WHERE t.contract_id = c.contract_id)
```

It works, but is it the performant way to do it? Is there a way to avoid the second `SELECT`?

Comment: What is your database name?

Comment: Database name is also contracts

Comment: I mean what is your RDBMS? Like MySQL or MSSQL or Other?

Comment: database is PostgreSQL

Comment: In general your query seems OK to me. But if you can add sample data from both table with exact expected output, this would help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also alternatively use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT * FROM contracts c LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (cd.contract_id) cd.* FROM contract_descriptions cd
    ORDER BY cd.contract_id, cd.date_description DESC
) d ON d.contract_id = c.contract_id
```

`DISTINCT ON` selects only one row per `contract_id` while the sort clause `cd.date_description DESC` ensures that it is always the last description.

Performance depends on many values (for example, table size). In any case, you should compare both approaches with `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks okay to me. One typical way to join only n rows by some order from the other table is a lateral join:

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT *
  FROM contract_descriptions cd
  WHERE cd.contract_id = c.contract_id
  ORDER BY cd.date_description DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) cdlast;
```